# Python - Atualizar todas as redes de uma lista

Tags: python, api, loop

Fiz um código em python que atualiza um **grupo de políticas de redes** de **uma rede** através da API da Cisco Meraki.

```
nereidas_lab = 'N_codigodarede'
group_policy_id = '101'

# Configurando a política selecionada.
politica_alterada = dashboard.networks.updateNetworkGroupPolicy(
    nereidas_lab, group_policy_id,
    name='Grupo Teste - Alterado via API',
    scheduling={'enabled': True, 'monday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                'tuesday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                'wednesday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                'thursday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                'friday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                'saturday': {'active': False, 'from': '0:00', 'to': '24:00'},
                'sunday': {'active': False, 'from': '0:00', 'to': '24:00'}},
)  
print('Ih, alá!', politica_alterada)
```

De fato, consegui alterar o meu grupo de políticas de UMA das minhas redes. Porém, gostaria de alterar essa política em todas as minhas redes, para isso fiz uma lista com as duas redes que possuo e estou tentando construir um loop para correr a lista e atualizar a política 101 nas duas redes. Segue o código do loop.

```
nereidas_redes_ids = ['N_codigorede1', 'N_codigorede2']
group_policy_id = '101'

for i in nereidas_redes_ids:
    nereidas_rede_atual = [i]

    politica_alterada = dashboard.networks.updateNetworkGroupPolicy(
        nereidas_rede_atual, group_policy_id,
            name='Grupo Teste - Alterado via API todas',
            scheduling={'enabled': True, 'monday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                        'tuesday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                        'wednesday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                        'thursday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                        'friday': {'active': True, 'from': '9:00', 'to': '17:00'},
                        'saturday': {'active': False, 'from': '0:00', 'to': '24:00'},
                        'sunday': {'active': False, 'from': '0:00', 'to': '24:00'}},
            bandwidth={'settings': 'custom', 'bandwidthLimits': {'limitUp': 1000000, 'limitDown': 1000000}},
        )
    
    print('Ih, alá!', politica_alterada)
```

Mas minhas políticas não estão atualizando. Conseguem me ajudar, por gentileza?

Comment: Mude de `nereidas_rede_atual = [i]` para `nereidas_rede_atual = i`. Parece que este parâmetro deve ser do tipo string e não do tipo lista.

Comment: No loop `for i in nereidas_redes_ids:` esta passando uma lista. O `dashboard.networks.updateNetworkGroupPolicy` espera um ID dessa rede como parâmetro.. Pode ser que para corrigir   passe o ID dessa rede diretamente para a função do que de criar uma nova lista.

Comment: codar esse loop: assim ... `for i in nereidas_redes_ids:
    politica_alterada = dashboard.networks.updateNetworkGroupPolicy(
        i, group_policy_id,
            name='Nome_grupo_valido',
            scheduling={`

Comment: Algumas coisas tem que levar em consideração **inválida a chave ou não tem as permissões necessárias para atualizar políticas de grupo,**   e tem **O Meraki tem limites de uso para suas APIs**

Comment: Obrigada, de fato alterar o parâmetro resolveu o problema. Agora não erro mais. Valeu!